# Is there a term for this concept in Statistics?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, time-series

I study statistics in network engineering.

In network engineering, network flow can be shaped.

For example, flow rates $X$ is sampled according to time,

$X =\{10\mathrm{Mbps}, 17\mathrm{Mbps}, 18\mathrm{Mbps}, \ldots\}$

then Flow $X$ can be shaped (limited) to $X' =\{9\mathrm{Mbps}, 9\mathrm{Mbps}, 9\mathrm{Mbps}, \ldots\}$ by using various mechanism like token bucket algorithm.

It is called the **flow shaping** in network engineering.

---

Mathematically, we can see that the time-series $X$ is transformed into $X'$

By transforming, each $X$ and $X'$ has a different distribution.

I know the concept of **Data transformation in Statistics** but this is is a little different because $X$ has a physical limitation. For example, $X$ cannot be transformed into $X' =\{20\mathrm{Mbps}, 20M\mathrm{Mbps}, 20\mathrm{Mbps}, \ldots\}$.

**Is there a term for this concept in Statistics?**

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I must admit this seems much too vague. I don't quite understand the concept you're asking about.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I really appreciate your comment. Then I need to make the question concrete and re-upload it. Thanks!